# Different image dimensions during training and testing time for FCNs

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, image-segmentation

I am reading multiple conflicting Stackoverflow posts and I'm really confused on what the reality is.

My question is the following. If I trained an FCN on `128x128x3` images, is it possible to feed an image of size `256x256x3`, or B)`128x128`, or C) neither since the inputs have to be the same during training and testing?

Consider SO [post #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241234/fully-convolution-networks-with-varied-inputs). In this post, it suggests that the images have to be the same dimensions during input and output. This makes sense to me.

SO [post #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050557/fully-convolutional-network-training-image-size): In this post, it suggests that we can forward a different sized image during test time and if you do some weird squeeze operations, this becomes possible. Not sure at all how this is possible.

SO [post #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331860/how-does-input-image-size-influence-size-and-shape-of-fully-connected-layer): In this post, it suggests that only the depth needs to be the same, not the height and width. How is this possible?

Bottom line as I understand it is, if I trained on `128x128x3`, then from the input layer to the first conv layer, **(1)** there is a fixed number of strides that take place. Consequently, **(2)** a fixed feature map size, and accordingly, **(3)** a fixed number of weights. If I suddenly change the input image size to `512x512x3`, there's no way that the feature maps from training and testing are even comparable, due to the difference in size **UNLESS**.

1. When I input an image of size `512x512`, then only the top `128x128` is considered and the rest of the image is ignored
2. The 512x512 image is resized before being fed to the network.

Can someone clarify this? As you can see there are multiple posts regarding this with not a canonical answer. Hence, a community aided answer that everyone agrees on would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between a "fully connected"/linear/inner-product layer and a convolution layer? For your questions it seems like you are confusing the two. please take a moment to reflect on the fundamental difference between these two layers and then I believe you'll understand how FCN networks can process arbitrary shaped inputs.

Comment: I do understand what the difference, but perhaps I'm not clearly conveying my confusion. Please see comment on thushv89's answer. @Shai

Comment: @Shai I get what you were saying now, thank you for the clarification +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my breakdown,

### Post 1

Yes, this is the standard way to do things. If you have variable sized inputs you crop/pad/resize them so that your inputs are all the same size.

### Post 2

Note tat this person is talking about a "fully convolutional network" not a "fully connected network". In a fully convolutional network, all the layers will be convolution layers and convolution layers have no issue with consuming arbitrary sized (width and height) inputs as long as the channel dimension is fixed.

The need to have fixed input size arises in standard convolutional networks because of the "flattening" done before feeding the convolution output to fully connected layers. So if you get rid of the fully connected layers (i.e. fully convolutional networks) you don't have that problem.

### Post 3

It is saying basically the same thing as Post 2 (in my eye). To summarise, if your convolution network has a fully connected layer, and you try to input variable sized inputs, you'll get a `RunTimeError`. But if you have a convolutional output and you input a `7x7x512` (h x w x channel) input you'll get a `(1x1x<output_channel>)` output, where if you input `8x8x512` input, you'll get a `(2x2x<output_channel>)` output (because of the convolution operation).

### Conclusion

The bottom line is that, if you're network has fully connected layers somewhere, you cannot directly feed variable sized inputs (without pad/crop/resize) but if your network is fully convolutional, you can.

One thing I don't know and can't comment is when the probability map is `[None, n, n, num_classes]` sized (as in Post #2), how to bring that to `[None, 1, 1, num_classes]` as you need to do that to perform `tf.squeeze`.

**Edit 1:**

### How the convolution kernel/input/output behave

I am adding this section to clarify how the input/output/kernel of a convolution operation behaves when input size changes. As you can see, a change in the input will change the size (that is, height and width dimensions). But the kernel (which is of shape `[height x width x in_channels x out_channels]` will not be affected during this change.

[image]

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I understand that fully convolutional network only has convolutional layers and that you can perform convolution on any sized image. However, let's say during training, you only used `64x64x3` image. Then the first convolutional layer (3x3 kernal and 1 stride, 0 padding) will output dimensions `62x62`. Then, during testing, if you use an image that's `128x128`, then you'll have `126x126` after convolution. If this is the case, then this will immediately cause a runtime error because the pretrained network only has weights to support a `62x62` feature map. This is my confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan this is exactly what you need to understand about convolution operation/layer. Please **write down** the mathematical operation a convolution layer performs on a 62x62 feature map and the *same* convolution on a 126x126. Make sure you understand that the number of *parameters* used in both cases is the same

Comment: @Jonathan, it won't result in a `RuntimeError`. I think you are confusing the input/output of a convolution layer with the actual kernel. The weights are for the kernel. When the input changes, the output size changes. But the kernel remains the same.

Comment: @Jonathan, I have updated the answer to reflect the explanation.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense and cleared up my confusion, thank you so much!